# Send an error to AJAX from PHP through JSON

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

ISSUE SOLVED BY ME.

OLD POST:

I am actually been working for this in weeks and nothing in the web seems to help.
I need to send a data from PHP to ajax through json so that a proper error prompt would occur.

Here is my AJAX splice.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "insert_account.php",
       dataType: "json",
   data: {'dataString' : dataString},
   success: function(data)
   {
         if(data.status == "error")
         {
            alert("ERROR");
         }
         else if(data.status == "success")
         {
            alert("SUCCESS");
         }
   },
```

and in my PHP it goes like this.

```
if($count > 0) //this count contains value to check if an account exists
{
      $response['status'] = "error";

}
else
{
    //QUERY TO INSERT NEW ACCOUNT
        $response['status'] = "success";
}
$count = 0;
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($response);
```

This doesn't seem to work and I have no idea why. Also, if it is successful it doesn't insert the data in the database though it works completely fine without ajax.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: THROUGH FIREBUG I HAVE SEEN THAT,

data.status returns an undefined VALUE because .status is not recognized by the ajax, therefore we truncate .status and use data only to fetch the encoded json_encode($response).

EDITED AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "insert_account.php",
       dataType: "json",
    data: {'dataString' : dataString},
       success: function(data)
       {
         if(data == "error")
         {
            alert("ERROR");
         }
            else if(data == "success")
            {
               alert("SUCCESS");
            }
       },
```

Hope I have helped others who experienced the same.

Comment: What is the exact response you get in the NET tab of the developer tools?

Comment: Do you mean, when I 'Inspect Element' the page and look for key and values? There's nothing in the local storage, it suppose to have key and values right?

Comment: No, the response of the `POST` request.

Comment: @jeroen additional info. : data.status contains a value of 200 after it went from PHP. I tried putting alert(data.status);

Comment: [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) can help you to find what are you sending via post in the console tab

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? The single argument of `data` should not have a responseCode associated with it unless you're using an incredibly old version of jQuery.

Comment: Version of JQUERY 1.10.2 @Ohgodwhy

Comment: @Emilio Gort what does firebug do?

Comment: There's no way that data.status returns '200' as there's no jqXHR object being evaluated as a single argument of `data` so there is certainly code here that is not being supplied to us.

Comment: That is all the code, I tried putting an alert to show what is really being returned and I just have no clue why it returns that. I thought it is supposed to tell that request succeeded. @Ohgodwhy

Comment: @Ohgodwhy have crhome a funcionality like the console tab in firebug where you can see the ajax request in detail?

Comment: @EmilioGort thanks for introducing firebug.

Comment: @Paolo:  If you have solved your problem, you should leave your question as it was and add/accept your solution as an answer.  This helps to identify the question as having been solved for others who may come across it later.